# Laravel cannot use mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get a database connection error when trying to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` within Laravel. Fluent queries work properly so I assume that the database has been configured correctly.

How should `mysql_real_escape_string()` be used from Laravel? I'm using it to escape the values in a SQL query that I need to build myself due to limitations of Fluent.

**PHP Code that builds my own SQL query**

```
    foreach($listings as $listing) {
        $listing = get_object_vars($listing);
        $query = 'INSERT IGNORE into archive ';
        $query .= '(' . implode(',', array_keys($listing)) . ') ';
        $query .= 'VALUES(' . implode(',', array_values( array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $listing) )) . ')';
        DB::query($query);
    }
```

**Error**

```
mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: 
Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), so there's no escaping, just prepared statements. See the [Laravel manual on databases](http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw).

Answer (score 19):

use `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote()` instead.

Comment: `DB::connection()->getPdo()->quote()` has not the same behaviour like `real_escape_string`, therefore a poor answer.

Answer (score 6):

`mysql_real_escapes_string()` uses a database link created with `mysql_connect()`, so it can only be used after you've called `mysql_connect()`.

An important note about this (from the comments):

> .. But shouldn't be used in environments where PDO is the database driver of choice. In fact, mysql_connect() shouldn't be used at all anymore. – Robin v. G.

Comment: .. But shouldn't be used in environments where PDO is the database interface of choice. In fact, mysql_connect() shouldn't be used at all anymore.

Answer (score 5):

My solution for this:

1. Create custom helpers file in app/lib/helpers.php
2. Add this to autoload in composer.json:

   ```
   "files": [
       "app/lib/helpers.php"
   ],
   ```
3. Add this function (found on php.net)

   ```
   if ( !function_exists('mysql_escape'))
   {
       function mysql_escape($inp)
       { 
           if(is_array($inp)) return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp);

           if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
               return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
           } 

           return $inp; 
       }
   }
   ```
4. `php artisan dump-autoload`

Now you can use mysql_escape everywhere in your code.

Comment: Please, don't do this... mysql_* have been deprecated for a while now.
Since PDO use prepared statements, you won't have a need to escape strings anymore :)